# Is it more "correct" to disable a function with a special value or a second parameter?

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns, coding-style

Say I have some function that I may or may not want to execute during a particular run of the code, and this function also takes some argument that is passed in as a parameter at runtime. Is there some guidance as to whether a second variable to enable/disable the execution of the function is warranted, or is a "special value" of the argument just as good? I like the idea of reducing the number of parameters but I can understand how the former might be more readable.

For example, consider a 'Delay' function (which we may or may not want to run and) which accepts 1 floating point argument for the length of the delay. We can then check first that the argument-parameter is positive, and if it is not, we can not bother calling the function at all. Is this bad code?

I generally write in C/C++ if that matters.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Please provide a [mre] that illustrates the situation.

Comment: Better to not call the function.

Comment: What you need is `overload` not check for arguments.

Comment: Is it bad code that a function `Delay(ms)` doesn't do anything when `ms <= 0`? Why should it? I mean, how would you expect a negative delay to work? A delay of 0 is the same as not delaying at all.  You could maybe throw an exception instead, but it's not really clear what your goal is.

Comment: mmiles19, `delay(t)` should work for all `t >= 0`.

Comment: Is your goal to optimize your program by avoiding a function call that is unnecessary for specific input values? In this case I suggest to do some profiling of your program to find out if this difference is really important. Optimization by the compiler might be sufficient or even better than your manual attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Given a predicate `p` the first option is to conditionally call the function:

```
if(p) Delay(42);
```

This makes the calling code a bit more verbose, but you don't have the overhead of the function call.  If the code uses lots conditions along those lines, it may obscure what is going on.  Error handling or if code is ported with lots of conditionally enabled code via macros comes to mind.

The 2nd option is to have a special value indicating that `Delay()` shouldn't do anything:

```
float t = 42;
if(!p) {
  t = 0;
}
...
Delay(t);
```

This means the disabling the feature is now both in the caller and in callee which I would consider a negative.  On the other hand, if the special case is an implementation detail of `Delay()`, say, you figure out a function call overhead is `delta` then you might have logic along these lines:

```
if(arg <= delta) return;
```

Now you are merely making use of that particular implementation detail.

Comment: `Delay(p ? 42 : 0)` only to have another branch within the function is... bizarre.

Comment: I don't know of a more concise way to express the conditional value...rewrote it using a variable if that is better.

Comment: The 2nd scenario is used usually when, say, you have `float dt = t1 - t2; Delay(dt);`. It's not used when you have a predicate telling you whether you should call `Delay` at all. There's a reason why people find the question confusing.

Comment: Good point but op talks about disabling code "may or may not want to execute".

Answer (score 0):

> check first that the argument-parameter is positive, and if it is not, we can not bother calling the function at all

This seems like a poor design, if we call the function, but some extra logic is there to decide, whether we should actually call it, based on current state.

However, if you want a single argument, which defines the delay value, but also could mean that there is no delay at all, you could use `std::optional`.
Still, it seems like a bad idea, to mix extra logic into this quite straightforward delay function. I'd focus on calling the delay function only when it's really needed.